# How to make a key simulate another key?

Tags: x11, keyboard, key-mapping

In my keyboard the <kbd>I</kbd> key doesn't work. So, I use an on-screen keyboard.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. But its hectic. Is there a way so that I can make another key (for example <kbd>Home</kbd> on my keypad) to behave like <kbd>I</kbd>?

Also, if you have any other easy way to achieve this please share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can re-map keys with `xmodmap`. E.g.:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 79 = i I"
```

To find correct keycode and alias use `xev`.

---

Looking around a bit: [this should give you needed details about persistent configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/24930/101774) etc.