# Before logging in my system, any way to make a key simulate another key?

Tags: x11, keyboard, keyboard-layout

In my keyboard <kbd>I</kbd> button doesn't work. I had earlier asked a Q on [how to make a key simulate another key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105980/how-to-make-a-key-simulate-another-key). That Q solved the issue only after I logged in my system. I'm working on Ubuntu 13.04. But how to solve the same issue that I'm facing before logging in my system? Take the below example:

While logging, in GRUB 2 boot menu, I press "c" & enter command line. Now here how to make a key simulate <kbd>I</kbd>? It would solve my issue completely if the change incorporated to achieve this is permanent in effect (whether I login or not; even if I boot into a different software, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If your grub CLI mode is similar to [this](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20CLI%20Mode%20Commands.html#CLI_Mode), then it has many standard features, including the `echo` command and support for variables, so most likely you could simply do:

```
A="$(echo -en '\0154')"
```

Then you would use it like this, for instance to do the `ls -l` command :)

```
$(echo $A)s -$(echo $A)
```

ALT+code is so much easier. But this is a last resort solution. Why "simulate" a key in that bash-like environment when you can simply generate the output with `echo` and the octal value for the character you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a PC, you can try the following:

- Hold down the ALT key
- Type the ASCII code on the keypad (108 for lowercase 'l')
- Let go of the ALT key

Make sure not to use the numbers at the top of the keyboard.  Also, this may only work with the left ALT key.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, if you can, just modifying your GDM so that it loads your `xmodmaps` as well. From this AU Q&A titled: [Why won't my ~/.Xmodmap file load on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7190/why-wont-my-xmodmap-file-load-on-login).

*excerpt*

> Also you could check `/etc/gdm/Xsession` for the line `usermodmap="$HOME/.Xmodmap"` and if it isn't there just append it at the end of the file. If you're the only user of the system just put your changes into `/etc/X11/Xmodmap`.

Comment: GDM + grub - is that possible?

Comment: @ash - my solution was only helping from GDM on. I hadn't noticed the GRUB part of his Q.